# $3$ mice in the corners of an equilateral triangle crawling at each other ODE problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At each corner of an equilateral triangle, a mouse is positioned. At time $t = 0$ the mice begin crawling towards each other. Mouse $1$ always crawls directly towards mouse $2$, mouse $2$ towards mouse $3$ and mouse $3$ towards mouse $1$. The speed of each mouse is equal to the vector of its position to the position of the mouse they are crawling towards.

> What does this last sentence mean?

Determine the trajectories of the mouse by creating a system of differential equations and solving it. What happes for $t \to +\infty$?
Note: It is advantageous to describe the position of the $k$-th mouse by a complex number $z_k$, $k = 1,2,3$. A skilful choice of the origin of the coordinate system is also advantageous

My try:

$z_1(t_0)=i,\ z_2(t_0)=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i,\ z_3(t_0)=\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i$

$z_2(t)=z_1(t)e^{\frac{4\pi}{3}i}=z_1(t)(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}i)$ (this is a rotation by $240°$)

I'm not sure sure if I can set the ODE like this:

$z_1'(t)=z_2(t)-z_1(t)=z_1(t)(-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{-\sqrt 3}{2}i)$

Therefore $z_1(t)=e^{(-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{2}i)t}c$ where $c=z_1(0)=i$.

And

$\lim_{t\to\infty}z_1(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}e^{-\frac{3}{2}t}(...)=0$

Comment: It should really say “The _velocity_ of each mouse...” Speed is usually a scalar quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/3}$. The three mice always form an equilateral triangle. Therefore we may write
$$z_k(t)=\omega^k \>z(t),\qquad z(0)=1\ .$$
According to the last sentence we have
$$\dot z_k(t)=z_{k+1}(t)-z_k(t)=(\omega-1)z_k(t)\ ,$$
so that we obtain the IVP
$$\dot z(t)=(\omega-1)\>z(t),\qquad z(0)=1$$
with solution
$$z(t)=e^{(\omega-1)t}=e^{-3t/2}\>e^{i\sqrt{3}\>t/2}\ .$$
The limit when $t\to\infty$ is then obvious.